# I can't find any .NET 4.0 application build with Windows Forms Controls and (or) Infragistics

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, controls, infragistics

I can't find any GUI application build with .NET 4.0 Windows Forms Controls and (or) Infragistics. Freeware or somewhat chip. Are there any?

.NET 4.0 would be ideal, but 4.5 or 4.7 are acceptable. Open source is preferred.

Comment: Googling for `windows forms sample projects` yields a lot of tutorials (which are, de facto, "open source applications"), so I'm not quite sure what exactly you are looking for...

Comment: Thanks for reply! I'm not a .NET developer and I'm trying to find ready-to-use Windows application with a various types of GUI controls. Tutorials are no way for me. Maybe a very long sample project packed with a lot of different controls would suit me if I manage to compile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab Windows Forms Samples from the [Download section under your Infragistics account](https://account.infragistics.com/downloads) if you've already signed up or alternatively you can always get a [Trial](https://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms) and the installer will also give you the option to install samples.

Those will come as pre-built running apps with a Browser app to navigate and besides component-specific ones, also include showcase samples with multiple controls which seem to match what you're looking for. All samples come with source code projects/solutions you can explore/run and those are still .NET4.
You can also have a look around our resources for docs and videos: https://www.infragistics.com/support/windows-forms-help

In any case, if you're absolutely new to this, it seems prudent to familiarize yourself with Windows Forms as a whole and [Microsoft's Docs for .NET 4.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) are still up. I'd stick to the designer topics as there's a lot you can do visually in Windows Forms :)

Comment: Thanks! If someone looking for a compiled binary I've found MusicBee which have different versions of .NET + Windows Forms.